# Sitecore Reference media library image in an image's src attribute inside Rich Text field editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm using sitecore 8.1, I have a template contains field of type "Rich Text", I'm creating items based on this template and storing HTML contents inside this field. All HTML tags and everything works properly except the images which included inside the HTML content (in src attribute), and I've tried all below scenarios but all fail:

> **Note:** All the following scenarios' results are showing the image properly inside the Rich Text Editor inside sitecore CMS but when trying to render the HTML in a mobile web view or any browser, the HTML looks properly but just images are empty.
>   And there is only one way I've tried and it worked but doesn't 
>   meet my requirements which is by mention an external URL inside src like:
>
> `src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg"`

**Scenarios:**

- Upload images inside media library and use Image Map Editor (called from Rich text editor) to reference the uploaded images, so the src attribute of image contains value like `src="-/media/5EA5C007FFFF4688A0B7E6F58B79D2E8.ashx?h=183&amp;w=250"`
  Here also I tried to change the extension from ashx to the original one and remove the postfix params but without result.
- Specify the image url inside the media library explicitly inside src attribute like
  `src="/-/media/Contents/Images/foobar"` And also here I tried to change add the original extension but without result.
- Use [this solution](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/12/sitecore-idiosyncrasies-media-urls.aspx) but it has currupted all my media files, also after I upload new files, still can't see images inside HTML web view or browser.
- Add the original images inside sitecore website directory like `\website\contents\images` and reference it like any normal image reference through HTML like
  `src="/contents/images/foobar.jpg"` and like `src="~/contents/images/foobar.jpg"` but without any result or change.

I prefer sure to avoid the last scenario by using Sitecore's Media Library

Comment: can you provide the URL that you see in the Front End

Comment: I find that the first scenario (after removing the postfix params and change the extension to the original one) is the most logic one because I'm getting src="-/media/411F4173DF814FBAAC9E9343FBE96442.jpg" in the front end and just should be prefixed with the root 'url + /' and it should work properly like: "www.mysite.com/-/media/411F4173DF814FBAAC9E9343FBE96442.jpg" but I don't know how to achieve it and don't want to mention the root url in the content editor(should be resolved in run time).

Comment: If you used the 'Insert Sitecore Media' option this it should insert the link (like in your first scenario) then the image link should be expanded correctly in normal mode. If it isn't something is wrong with your configuration or it has been overridden by your implementation possibly.

Comment: @jammykam thanks but I'm still getting same result, it should be working properly by default configuration (coz I've never changed it), and by the way I've updated my question to show how I'm requesting this HTML(might be something I'm missing)

Comment: Still the same answer I'm afraid. I would raise a ticket with Sitecore Support who will be better able to deal with your issue looking at your configurations and log files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the ashx extension, you can use the sitecore path of the image directly in the rich text as shown below:

`src="~/media/path/to/image/logo.jpg"`

Then as you provided above, you retrieve the value from the Rich Text as below:

```
var richTextValue = item.Fields["Body"].Value;
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem with this is if the image is moved or renamed then you end up with a broken image link. My using the default guid format this is also handled for you. You also break the link and will not be warned of usage when you delete an image. I'd regard this as bad practice.